# Could not find goal 'update-theme' in plugin com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.1.1 among available goals build-frontend, prepare-frontend

Tags: vaadin

I have started using Vaadin 23 which is launched recently. But when I'm trying to compile theme its not working. Below is the message I'm getting on console.

BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'update-theme' in plugin com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.1.1 among available goals build-frontend, clean-frontend, dance, prepare-frontend

Answer (score 1):

Many things have changed since Vaadin 8. There is no more `update-theme`. You should create a new [template project](https://start.vaadin.com/) and use that as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin 23 uses plain CSS instead of SCSS, so it doesn't need to be compiled. Thus there is no need for an "update-theme" goal.